# getting Rank deficiency error in cross validation

Tags: r, cross-validation, knn, predictive, loocv

Hi I am trying to cross validate my multiple logistic predictive model. I have used the following code before on the same data before and it never gave me an issue but now its giving the rank deficiency error. Any help would be appreciated.

```
quadratic <- qda(Outcome ~ Var1 + Var2 + Var3 + Var4, data = DATA, prior = c(0.14 , 0.86))
quadratic

## Data explanation below
## Var1: binary data
## Var2: Continuous data
## Var3: Continuous data
## Var4: Continuous data


0.14: 14% prevalance of disease in the population
0.86: 100-0.14
```

The error I am getting is the following:

```
"Error in qda.default(x, grouping, ...) : rank deficiency in group 1"
```

I tried removing the prior part of the command but I am still getting the error. I also tried to remove the most collinear variable which is Var2 but I am getting the same error.